# How can I display ListView Items in a Grid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to recreate something similar to this gallery in `Xamarin Forms`. I want a `ListView` with grouping and it's items displayed in a grid. 
I know how to group items in a `ListView`, but I don't know how to display the items in a grid. The grid layout looks similar to a `Flex Layout` but as far as I can see a Flex Layout doesn't have a way to group items. How can I create this in Xamarin?

[image]

Comment: use CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the new `CollectionView` for this:

Eg code:

```
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="collectionView"
            Margin="5"
            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
            SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                 </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="10"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2" 
                    VerticalItemSpacing="10" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label
                        FontSize="Title"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Text="{locale:Translate Global_No_Data_Found}"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
        </CollectionView>
```

Here ItemsLayout is what defines how your Items will look options are Grid and Linear.
To add the date part as per the Image use Group header templates just like ListView.
Note that `CollectionView`DataTemplates take Views and not ViewCells.
Using ViewCell will throw an exception of the unspecified cast.

More about CollectionView can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid

Feel free to get back in case of queries.